# TypeError no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hash

```
data = {
  :recordset => {
    :row => {
      :property => [
        {:name => "Code",     :value => "C0001"}, 
        {:name => "Customer", :value => "ROSSI MARIO"}
      ]
    }
  },
  :@xmlns => "http://localhost/test"
}
```

Code Used

```
result = data[:recordset][:row].each_with_object([]) do |hash, out|
           out << hash[:property].each_with_object({}) do |h, o|
                    o[h[:name]] = h[:value]
                  end
         end
```

I cannot get the following output:

```
[{"Code"=>"C0001", "Customer"=>"ROSSI MARIO", "Phone1"=>"1234567890"}
```

Error message:

> TypeError no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

It works correctly in case of multi records

```
data = {
  :recordset => {
    :row => [{
      :property => [
        {:name => "Code",     :value => "C0001"},
        {:name => "Customer", :value => "ROSSI MARIO"},
        {:name => "Phone1",   :value => "1234567890"}
      ]
    }, {
      :property => [
        {:name => "Code",     :value => "C0002"},
        {:name => "Customer", :value => "VERDE VINCENT"},
        {:name => "Phone1",   :value => "9876543210"},
        {:name => "Phone2",   :value => "2468101214"}
      ]
    }]
  },
  :@xmlns => "http://localhost/test"
}
```

Code used

```
data.keys
#=> [:recordset, :@xmlns] 

data[:recordset][:row].count
#=> 2   # There are 2 set of attribute-value pairs


result = data[:recordset][:row].each_with_object([]) do |hash, out|
           out << hash[:property].each_with_object({}) do |h, o|
                    o[h[:name]] = h[:value]
                  end
         end
#=> [
#   {"Code"=>"C0001", "Customer"=>"ROSSI MARIO", "Phone1"=>"1234567890"},
#   {"Code"=>"C0002", "Customer"=>"VERDE VINCENT", "Phone1"=>"9876543210", "Phone2"=>"2468101214"}
# ]
```

Comment: I'd recommend using [`#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-map) instead of the first [`#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object). Furthermore using [`#merge!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) might be more readable than the nested square brackets. https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/be7bb470b4804ef39883ff67bdfd2e10

Answer (score 5):

In the first case `data[:recordset][:row]` is not an Array, it's a Hash, so when you iterate it, the `hash` variable becomes the array:

```
[:property, [{:name=>"Code", :value=>"C0001"}, {:name=>"Customer", :value=>"ROSSI MARIO"}]]
```

In the second case, it's an Array, not a Hash, so when you iterate it, it becomes the hash:

```
{:property=>[{:name=>"Code", :value=>"C0001"}, {:name=>"Customer", :value=>"ROSSI MARIO"}, {:name=>"Phone1", :value=>"1234567890"}]}
```

You're always assuming it's the second format. You could force it into an array, and then flatten by 1 level to treat both instances the same:

```
result = [data[:recordset][:row]].flatten(1).each_with_object([]) do |hash, out|
  out << hash[:property].each_with_object({}) do |h, o|
    o[h[:name]] = h[:value]
  end
end

# => [{"Code"=>"C0001", "Customer"=>"ROSSI MARIO"}] # result from example 1
# => [{"Code"=>"C0001", "Customer"=>"ROSSI MARIO", "Phone1"=>"1234567890"},
#     {"Code"=>"C0002", "Customer"=>"VERDE VINCENT",
#      "Phone1"=>"9876543210", "Phone2"=>"2468101214"}] # result from example 2
```

---

It's tempting to try and use [`Kernal#Array()`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Array) instead of `[].flatten(1)`, but you have to remember that Hash implements `to_a` to return a nested array of keys and values, so `Kernal#Array()` doesn't work like you'd want it to:

```
Array(data[:recordset][:row]) # using the first example data
# => [[:property, [{:name=>"Code", :value=>"C0001"}, {:name=>"Customer", :value=>"ROSSI MARIO"}]]]
```

Comment: Instead of `[data[:recordset][:row]].flatten(1)` you could also use `Array(data[:recordset][:row])` which I find cleaner myself. `Array(1) #=> [1]` and `Array([1]) #=> [1]`

Comment: Ah, easily forgotten. Nice catch.

Comment: @JohanWentholt maybe I should have left my original comment :) as I said the same exact thing and was necessarily corrected as well as I forgot about the progression of `to_ary`, `to_a`, then array wrapping :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array if it's not an array to normalize the input before processing it.

```
info = data[:recordset][:row]
info = [info] unless info.is_an? Array
result = info.each_with_object([]) do ....
```